# Getting a new passport from "Country-B" while on L1 in USA on "Country-A" passport?

Tags: visas, usa

I am in a situation where I will be working in US on L1 on "A" passport, and few months down the line will be getting the "B" passport. So in this case if I surrender my "A" passport I will lose my L1 and the employer will have to re issue a new one. Country "A" does not allow dual citizenship so have to surrender "A" passport.

Is it possible to transfer the L1 from "A" to "B"? What are the cost implications for the employer here? I believe employer generally gets the blanket L1s, so should they have any problem issuing the L1 on "B" passport?

Any suggestions/experience. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean 'Country "A" does NOT allow dual citizenship'?

Comment: Are you just getting a new passport or actually changing your citizenship?  Also, employers do not issue visas.  The department of state does that.

Comment: Yes, A does not allow dual citizenship. And, I am changing citizenship as A & B are different countries, should have clarified that. Sorry.

Comment: I made the edit for you clarifying that A does not allow dual citizenship.

Comment: This belongs on expats rather than travel, but the answer is simple - talk to your companies immigration lawyers.  If they don't have one, get one!

Comment: This has been transferred to expats.

Answer (score 2):

Your original post is unclear but I think you’re saying that:

- you have a L1 on Passport A and entered the USA on it
- while you’re in the USA you want to renew Passport B which is expiring
- Country B doesn’t allow for dual nationality so you can’t reveal the existence of Passport A
- you’re in the USA and you’re worried that when you’re renewing B that they’ll ask you what your status is and you can’t say L1 as it’s on your Passport A and you can’t say visa waiver or other short term visa as you don’t have the entry stamp AND/OR country B won’t renew passports of people on short stay visas.

In these cases, the best thing is to return to Country B and renew there. If you’re already planning an extended trip to Country D then you could try that but you’d need a few months for a plausible rationale and your L1 might preclude that.

Comment: I will clarify it again- Country A & B are different. A does not allow dual citizenship. I entered USA on A with L1. Passport B is not renewed, it is a new passport from a different country. Once i get B, i will have to surrender A. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sound" in your other answer. This answer no longer answers the question asked, so it should be deleted.